# Compare two characters using Bitwise operators

Tags: c, compare, bit-manipulation

I need to compare two characters as followed in the example:
EXAMPLE:

```
COMPARE('a','z') Will return -1
COMPARE('a','A') Will return -1
COMPARE('g','g') WIll return 0
COMPARE('A','a') Will return 1
```

In general, I need to Compare them just like in the Function: `strcmp()`,
But I need to use bitwise operators for the Comparsion.
Here is what I did for now.

```
int Lcmp(char unsigned first,char unsigned sec)
{
    int i;
    char unsigned mask=0x80; //mask = 10000000 in binary
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        if(first&mask&&(!(sec&mask)))  //first>sec, Beacuase first had the sum 2^7
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if((!(first&mask))&&(sec&mask)) //first<sec " " " "
        {
            return -1;
        }
        mask>>=1; //move the comparsion bit rigth
    }
    return 0; //CASE: first==sec
}
```

My problem is; this code doesn't work.
And when I mean doesn't work: Its always giving me FALSE result without any pattern.
Please repair it, thanks.
NOTE: i need the function should compare in dictionary

EDIT:

```
I added this statment after the mask decleretion.
    if(first<'a'&&sec>='a')
            first^=mask;
        else if(first>='a'&&sec<'a')
            sec^=mask;
```

What i did is to remove the MSB iff one of them is upper, giving an advetege to the lower case letter.

Comment: But method finishes in the first if-clause because it always returns something which ends the Lcmp.

Comment: You should run it through a debugger, and step through the function line by line while monitoring the variables and the expressions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Have a look at this comment of the OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389530/sorting-text-file-with-bubble-sort-in-c#comment25245963_17389530.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg how do i repesent a variable in the debugger(visual studio) in binary base?.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik no it isent. beacuse if first in binary=01111111 then first&mask==0

Comment: @G.w.Weil: I cannot reproduce your problem. `Lcmp('a', 'A')` returns 1, `Lcmp('A', 'a')` returns -1, and `Lcmp('x', 'x')` returns 0.

Comment: @G.w.Weil why don't you use first xor sec ?

Comment: @MartinR i need Lcmp('a',A') return -1, beacuase 'a' come before 'A' in the ascii table.

Comment: @banarun I dont recongize how it will help me with my problem/

Comment: @G.w.Weil `A` comes before `a` http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: from right to left xor each bit of first and sec, if they are different at some point, the one with set bit is greater.

Comment: @Armin sory about that, i meant Alpha Betical

Comment: @banarun it not work/ 100000010 XOR 0100000001, i think you mean left to right

Comment: "beacuase 'a' come before 'A' in the ascii table" -- Where did you get that idea? It's wrong.

Comment: If you compare the ASCII values, how can expect to get a different ordering such as "alphabetical" (however that is defined) ?

Comment: @JimBalter Sory, how can i compare letter that in the UPPER_CASE section with letter in LOWER_CASE section? Lcmp('A','a') should return 1, but it return -1

Comment: @MartinR How is that define ? (i can learn somthing new), 2. how can i sort by alphabetical?

Comment: Armin already answered that question.

Comment: Thank Guys, I figure it out. should i edit my post to the fixed code(for future users) or its agianst the rules?.

Comment: @G.w.Weil: You can answer your own question.

Comment: @MartinR i just try it. it said only after 6-8 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equality is easy to check for with xor.

Assuming the case is significant, the upper and lower case characters differ at bit 6 so masking with 0x20 checks the case so:

```
int Lcmp(char unsigned first,char unsigned sec)
{
        unsigned char diff = first^sec;
        if (!diff)
        {
                // bits the same
                return 0;
        }

        if (diff & 0x20)
        {
                // case differs
                if (first & 0x20)
                {
                        // sec is capital
                        return -1;
                }
                // first is capital
                return 1;
        }

        // same case - find highest different bit
        char unsigned mask=0x80;
        while (!(mask & diff))
        {
                mask >>=1;
        }

        if (first & mask)
        {
                // first has highest differentbit set
                return 1;
        }

        // sec has highest different bit set 
        return -1;
}
```